# What is the meaning of double colon in spring framework modelandview?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I don't know how can I explain this symptom in the web page.
Because when I enter the double colon in the URL, some of a tags are found on the web page.

the url like below

```
/birthday?birthday=20160102::a
```

the controller code like below.

```
public ModelAndView birthday(String birthday) throws Exception
{
    List<String> birthdays = Arrays.asList("20160102", "20160103");
    if (birthday== null || birthday.length() == 0)
        birthday = birthdays.get(0);

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("user/information/day-" + birthday);
    mav.addObject("birthdays", birthdays);
    mav.addObject("birthday", birthday);
    return mav;
}
```

the web page is used thymeleaf and microsoft office css.

```
day-20160102.html
```

I can't figure out why this works?
Would you give me some tips or a way to approach this situation?

Comment: it's hardnut to get crack what you actually want to know?

Comment: I just want to know why the double colon works in the url. Because I think modelandview just return the webpage.